# how to get a timeline hover animation to stop when a certain id is visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am busy working on a timeline, the basic left right function of it works
the current issue I am having is that the hover function moves the timeline further than I need. I had an idea to stop the animation when the last li (#last) is visible and vise versa when the first li (#first) is visible. I think that my implementation of the jQuery might be wrong and would appreciate your assistance please. See below a JSFIDDLE and the jQuery code.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Jason1975/6nwkd2c8/84/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("li#last:visible")) {
        stop();
    } else {
        $("a#next").click(function () {
            $("#new").animate({
                "left": "-=100px"
            }, 200); 
        });
    }

    if ($("li#first:visible")) {
        stop(); 
    } else {
        $("a#prev").hover(function () {
            $("#new").animate({
                "left": "+=100px"
            }, 200);
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Which browsers does this not work in? I tried it in Chrome 39, FF 32, and IE 11 and it works as expected.

Comment: Did you check the documentation for [`:visible`](http://api.jQuery.com/visible-selector/), or did it just 'sound right,' from the name?

Comment: Hi Mark I have tried this on Chrome 40, FF32 and IE11 it does not work in any, could the fact that we are testing in JSFIDDLE affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few things I had to change. First was your markup never had a positioning that was able to be moved. So I added `position:relative;` to `#new`.

```
<ul id="new" style="width: 1025px; position:relative;">
```

Note I also removed the translate property as you were using jQuery's animate, and translate is for CSS3 animations.

I also changed the hover functions to this:

```
    var containerWidth = $('#container').width(); 
    $('a#next').hover(function(){
        $("#new").animate({
            "left": -Math.abs(containerWidth) - 150
        }, 1000);
    }, function(){
        $("#new").stop();
    });
    $('a#prev').hover(function(){
        $("#new").animate({
            "left": 50
        }, 1000);
    }, function(){
        $("#new").stop();
    });
```

And added it inside your document.ready function. I hope this helps!

Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6nwkd2c8/88/).